# What happenes if i open a FIFO for read and write in the same program?

Tags: named-pipes, fifo

I started to learn pipes and FIFO and i don t understand exactly what happens in the background in this situation.Why nothing is printed in the console? No other process opens the "abc" FIFO

```
`int r,w,n=7;
r=open("abc",O_RDONLY);
n--;
w=open("abc",O_WRONLY);
n--;
printf("%d",n);`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using named pipes in a single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251710/using-named-pipes-in-a-single-process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435538/139985 explains, when you open a FIFO, the open call will block until the system gets a corresponding open on the the other side of same FIFO.

In your example, you have a single-threaded C program that attempts to open both sides one after the other.  That won't work.  The program will just *lock up*.

If you redesign your program to use two threads and open the read and write ends of the FIFO in different threads, that should work.  One thread will block in `open` until the other thread calls `open`.

However, using a FIFO to communicate between two threads in the same application is (to say the least) inefficient.